# How to set Dialog text position from code?

Tags: dialog, position, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

Good day all,
I have a simple `Dialog` started after click button, I post my code:

```
Dialog dialog;

super();

dialog = new Dialog("Dialog example");

dialog.addText(strFmt("Text to show"));
dialog.addText(strfmt("SecondText to show"));

dialog.run();
```

I will show a `Dialog` window loollike this :

[image: My Dialog]

It's possible to set the position from code the Text: *Text to show* ?
For example, if I want to centered position the second text how should I do?

I tried to put blanks in the code:

```
dialog.addText(strfmt("       Text to show"));
```

But nothing changes, and this I think not good method.
I saw any suggestions on Web but or I do not use well or is not suitable for me: [Example-suggestions](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/microsoftdynamicsaxtechnicaltutorials/archive/2013/12/06/how-to-set-position-of-dialog-box-in-axapta).
Exist a method to do what I want?

Thanks for help,

enjoy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can center the text using the form control:

```cpp
Dialog dialog = new Dialog("Dialog example");
DialogText t1 = dialog.addText(strFmt("Text to show"));
DialogText t2 = dialog.addText(strfmt("SecondText to show"));
FormStaticTextControl c1 = t1.control();
c1.widthMode(FormWidth::ColumnWidth);
c1.alignment(FormAlignment::Center);
dialog.run();
```

The first control is now centered (to the surrounding group).
You have to give it `ColumnWidth`, otherwise the control would have the minimum size and the centering would have no effect.